# How to send mail from windows phone with attachment programmatically?

Tags: namespaces, gmail, windows-phone-8

I want to send a mail with attachment from my emulator. But in some article I saw that it  uses the `system.web.dll` namespace. I don't have that namespace.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a built in way to do this with WP8. A quick Google search came up with [MailMessage](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/send-email-with-attachments-without-using-emailcomposetask-with-mailmessage). From the article:

> MailMessage is a great component which fills a big hole on WP7/8 SDK,
>   you can now finally send unattended emails with attachments from your
>   app without using EmailComposeTask, and you can attach any type of
>   file (pdf, mp3, wav, mp4, avi, bmp, txt, zip, jpg, png...).

Here's a [link to download](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage). It's not free, but there is a free trial.

Comment: Thank you Friend........ I already use this article for send mail with attachment........ But I thing it's some third party service. But I want no use any third party services for sending mail.

Comment: Correct - MailMessage is a 3rd party component. As it stands, I don't think the functionality you want is built in to WP8 yet.